# Can you specify which buffer to send to in MPI?

Tags: buffer, mpi, openmpi

Say, if you did two `MPI_Sends` and two `MPI_Recvs`, can you specify which buffer the contents of the `MPI_Send` will go to, if you have two different buffers available and each of the `MPI_Recvs` receives from each of the buffers?

```
if(rank == MASTER) {
   for(kk=1; kk < size; kk++) { 
      MPI_Recv(printbuf, numcols, MPI_DOUBLE, kk, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
      sum = sum + printbuf[kk-1];
    }
 }
 else {
   MPI_Send(sum, local_ncols + 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }
 if(rank == MASTER) {
   for(kk=1; kk < size; kk++) {   
     MPI_Recv(secondbuf, numcols, MPI_DOUBLE, kk, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
     sum2 = sum2 + secondbuf[kk-1];
   }
 }
 else {
   MPI_Send(sum2, local_ncols + 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }
```

This is with OpenMPI. Each rank calculates `sum` and `sum2`. I want to obtain the summation of all the ranks' `sum`s and `sum2`s. Is there a better way? For instance, by being able to specify which buffer to send `sum` and `sum2`, can the below code be condensed?

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid the use of reduce operation?

Comment: @Idempotence thanks, I will try that

Comment: @Angelos could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Angelos's comment is right: if you're trying to sum results from all processes, [`MPI_Reduce`](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) [(e.g., this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14813595/463827), [amongst others)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mpi_reduce+%5Bmpi%5D) is the way to go.

Answering the general question as posed, though: when you send a message, you can't control what the receiving process does with it - all you're doing is sending it.  However, there is one piece of metadata you can control beside which task you're sending it to: the tag.  The receiving process can decide what buffer to receive into based on the tag:

```
if (rank != MASTER) {
    // worker process
    MPI_Send(sum1, local_ncols + 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(sum2, local_ncols + 2, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else {
    // master process
    MPI_Recv(printbuf, numcols, MPI_DOUBLE, kk, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    MPI_Recv(secondbuf, numcols, MPI_DOUBLE, kk, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
}
```

There are other approaches you can take, as well.  You can use MPI's [non-overtaking guarantee](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node41.htm), which states that two messages from task1 to task2 with the be received in the same order as they are sent if they can be received by the same receive - this ensures that the receiving process can distinguish the first message sent from the second one.

Another approach which can work in some contexts is to pack them into the same message (this can be useful for short messages to reduce latency) and unpack them on the receiving side; this is another way of ensuring that you know which piece of data is going into which buffer.

Comment: Thanks, these approaches are really helpful

Comment: Also, in response to the link of your answer to a similar question - if you do the reduce within a function and you want to return the sum of all the ranks' sums (i.e. globalsum), how is this possible? It looks like you can only use globalsum from the MASTER rank.

Comment: @FullMetalScientist - If you want all ranks to get the final answer, you would use `MPI_Allreduce` - see, e.g., http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce